# How to make routing on edges of a router in center of OSPF routing?

Tags: routing, router, ospf

Lets says I have 3 routers: R1, R2, R3... All three communicate with OSPF (with authentication and all) ... R1 <--> R2 <--> R3

Now I have R4 on one side of R1 ...

R4 <--> R1 <--> R2 <--> R3 .... But R4 is not using OSPF.

My problem is that it can only ping the one interface of R1 it is connected to.

I want it to be able to ping any interfaces of others but WITHOUT OSPF...I tried a static route but it did not work...

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to configure static routes on the other routers. Routers learn routes in three ways:

- Directly connected networks
- Statically configured routes
- Dynamically through routing protocols

You must configure R4 with static routes to all the networks to which it is not directly connected, or use a static default route, pointing to R1.

R2 and R3 must have the networks for R4 statically defined, or you can include the R1 interface to R4 in the OSPF process.

Ping is bidirectional. It sends an ICMP echo request, and the pinged device must send an ICMP echo reply. If the pinged device does not have a route to the originating network, then it will not reply, and ping will fail.

Comment: I don't know why but adding the R1 interface facing R4 in OSPF (network, area, authentication, etc...) did not allow R4 to ping the others (nor the R1 interface facing R2)

Comment: R4 needs routes to the other routers, just as the other routers need routes back to the R4 networks. You must have both. If you still have problems, then edit your question to include your router configurations, routing tables, and OSPF databases.

Comment: I've configured static as you said. It worked...I think I'll stick to that (only 20 routes to configure lol ) Thank you mate. You've helped me a lot today.

Answer (score 0):

If three routers are using OSPF and one router is using static routing

To ensure communication among this networks, the solution is redistribution

Redistributes the routes into static to OSPF .